# Sequelize - subquery in where clause

Tags: orm, subquery, where-clause, sequelize.js

I'm using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) in my Express app. I need to generate a query that has a subquery in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE id NOT IN (
       SELECT fkey
         FROM MyOtherTable
        WHERE field1 = 1
          AND field2 = 2
          AND field3 = 3
       )
```

I first tried relations/associations through my models but couldn't get it to work. Something like:

```js
MyTable.find( {
    where: {
        id: {
            $notIn: // <= what goes here? Can I somehow reference my include model?
        }
    },
    include: [ {
        model: MyOtherTable,
        where: {
          field1: 1,
          field2: 2,
          field3: 3
    } ]
} );
```

Then I tried using `Sequelize.where()`, no luck there.

Then I tried `Sequelize.literal()` and that works but not sure if it's a *"proper"* way of doing a subquery in a where clause in Sequelize as I'm new to it.

```js
MyTable.find( {
    where: {
        id: {
            $notIn: sequelize.literal( 
                '( SELECT fkey ' +
                    'FROM MyOtherTable ' +
                   'WHERE field1 = ' + field1 +
                    ' AND field2 = ' + field2 +
                    ' AND field3 = ' + field3 + 
                ')'
        }
    } 
} );
```

I also know that I could use `Sequelize.query()` but don't really know if I should reach for it or if `literal()`is the right away as I feel like there's something I'm overlooking.

I would really like to know how to perform a subquery in a `WHERE` clause with Sequelize the *"proper"* way.

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Looking at SO I came to this github issue https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3961, through this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882185/sequelize-statementwhere-in-statementwhere/39040218#39040218, and apparently using sequelize.literal is the only way for the time being.

Comment: Seems like using `sequelize.literal(...)` is still the way to go

Comment: I found this src that may help you (UNTESTED). let me know of your test after you follow this http://srlm.io/2015/02/04/sequelize-subqueries/

Comment: wouldn't this solution allow sql injection?

Comment: @Sash depends on the source of `field1`, `field2`, `field3` and/or if they've already been sanitized/escaped. For this example the values are defined on the backend.

Comment: I've added an example snippet of how I use it my code. It's a different approch.

Comment: If you are not using data from the client(s) consuming the API (no need to worry about SQL injection), your solution works perfectly already. And it's easier to implement than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I have encountered a similar issue in my project.
The way I choose to implement it is a bit different for two reasons:

1. If at one point in time Sequelize decides to implement sub queries - the syntax is ready.
2. Use Sequelize protection against SQL injection.

Here is my code snippet, hope it helps.

**Sequelize v5**

```js
const tempSQL = sequelize.dialect.QueryGenerator.selectQuery('MyOtherTable',{
    attributes: ['fkey'],
    where: {
          field1: 1,
          field2: 2,
          field3: 3
    }})
    .slice(0,-1); // to remove the ';' from the end of the SQL

MyTable.find( {
    where: {
        id: {
              [Sequelize.Op.notIn]: sequelize.literal(`(${tempSQL})`)
        }
    } 
} );
```

**Sequelize v6**

```js
const tempSQL = sequelize.dialect.queryGenerator.selectQuery('MyOtherTable',{
    attributes: ['fkey'],
    where: {
          field1: 1,
          field2: 2,
          field3: 3
    }})
    .slice(0,-1); // to remove the ';' from the end of the SQL

MyTable.find( {
    where: {
        id: {
              [Sequelize.Op.notIn]: sequelize.literal(`(${tempSQL})`)
        }
    } 
} );
```

Some people might choose to not use the tempSQL variable and simply build the SQL inside the find structure (maybe using a helper method?)

I also think this might be the basis for a sub queries extension for sequelize as it uses the same syntax almost.

Comment: Are `where` objects in SQL generator and in find query safely interchangeable? Can I use the same syntax here and there?

Comment: ASFAIK yes. The `find` method uses the `QueryGenerator` internally. That's how I came with this approach in the 1st place.

Comment: Thank you. This saved me when I needed to use limit/offset with `where` for included model. I generated a subquery like you show here and it works like charm.

Comment: This looks very nice solution. But unfortunately it did not work for me. dialect property does not exist in sequelize variable. Is this because of different latest version I am using?

Comment: Are you using v6 or v5? On v6 try to use getDialect()

Comment: I am using v6 but getDialect() method is not available to use

Comment: Whenever I use this Sequelize.getDialect() it shows this error:
Property 'getDialect' does not exist on type 'typeof import("node_modules/sequelize/types/index")'.ts(2339)

Comment: It exists in the code - https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/e05351492ac535f7eff977e29041c4a2eb4ee0d6/src/sequelize.js#L378
but I'm not using v6 as of yet myself...

Comment: @AyyazZafar `sequelize.getDialect()` is an instance method - **NOT** static method

Comment: Ok i tried .getDialect() from instance method but then getDialect().QueryGenerator was not available

Comment: @AyyazZafar if you'll look at the v5 to v6 migration guide (https://sequelize.org/master/manual/upgrade-to-v6.html), you'll see they changed `QueryGenerator ` to `queryGenerator`

>> All instances of QueryInterface and QueryGenerator have been renamed to their lowerCamelCase variants eg. queryInterface and queryGenerator when used as property names on Model and Dialect, the class names remain the same.

Comment: Okay thanks but actually .getDialect() returns only a string == 'mysql' 
That's why we cannot use .getDialect().queryGenerator() :(

Comment: I tried both `Sequelize.mysql.queryGenerator.selectQuery(...)` and `Sequelize.mysql.QueryGenerator.selectQuery(...)` - both result in an error `cannot read property selectQuery of undefined`.

Comment: @Eggon Which version of Sequelize are you using?

Comment: @ShaharHadas I'm using v. 5.21.3.

Comment: @Eggon just realized you are calling `Sequelize.mysql...` and not `sequelize.dialect...` which is using the sequelize connection instance.  Look at the examples above

Comment: @ShaharHadas I see, I read more thoroughly other comments here, I was able to do it using the Sequelize instance. Thanks! Upvoted the answer now! :)

Comment: Note that `selectQuery` doesn't support some options that `findAll` and the like support; for instance, `paranoid`.  You'll have to invoke some more internal methods in order for them the work; for instance, `selectQuery(..., Model._paranoidClause(options))`.

Comment: This works for me `sequelize.getQueryInterface().queryGenerator.selectQuery`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Shahar Hadas answer, because i fall into some errors using the code he showed.

Here is a more complexe example. In this example we have a main table named "Artist" in a Many-to-Many relationship with "Tag". "Tag" are associated to a predefined list of tags i named "TagType".
We want to fetch all Artists linked to all the searched tags (TagType Id).

```js
const tagsSearched = [1, 2];

const subQueryOptions = {
    attributes: ['id'], // You have to list at least one attribute
    include: [
        {
            model: models.Tag,
            required: true,
            attributes: [], // Avoid the only_full_group_by error
            through: {
                attributes: [], // Avoid the only_full_group_by error
            },
            include: {
                model: models.TagType,
                required: true,
                attributes: [], // Avoid the only_full_group_by error
                where: {
                    id: {
                        [Op.in]: tagsSearched, // Array of tags searched
                    }
                },
            },
        }
            ],
    group: sequelize.col('artist.id'), // Group by the main parent ID of this query
    having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('count', 
            sequelize.col('tags.tagType.id')), {
                [Op.gte]: tagsSearched.length,
    }), // Get only the artists that have at least the "tagsSearched" associated
}

// Parse the subQueryOptions, this operation would serialize the queryOptions
Model._validateIncludedElements.bind(models.Artist)(subQueryOptions);

// First argument has to be a string (table name, by default in plural)
// Second argument is our serialized query options
// Third argument is the model used
const artistsSubQuery = sequelize.dialect.queryGenerator.selectQuery("artists", subQueryOptions, models.Artist)
.slice(0,-1); // to remove the ';' from the end of the SQL query

models.Artist.findAll({
    where: {
        id: {
            [Op.in]: sequelize.literal(`(${artistsSubQuery})`),
        }
    }
});
```

I will update this in case of questions.