# Node Sequelize ORM JOIN tables without loading records from the JOIN table

Tags: sequelize.js

How do you perform a simple inner join without eagerly loading the results of the JOIN table in Sequelize?

The following query correctly joins the `book`s table and only returns records that have an associated books record, great.

I don't want the data from the `books` table to be populated in the dataset though.

Example:

If the parent model is say: a shelf.  I want to find all the shelves that currently have any books in them...but I do not want to return all the book data, I just need the parent shelf records.

```
this.getModel().findAll(
{
    include: [
        {
            model: this.db.getModel('books'),
            required: true,
        }
    ]
});
```

**How do I just return the parent table data based on the join?**
The docs are very confusing.

Comment: You are going to need to perform a custom query. JOINs are for actually JOINing data - not for loading data that meets a certain condition. You need to build a `WHERE id IN (SELECT shelf_id FROM books)`:

Comment: Ok, this makes sense I think. Thanks.

Comment: Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164694/sequelize-subquery-in-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

You can list what attributes you want to load with `attributes`.  In your case, an empty array.

```
this.getModel().findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: this.db.getModel('books'),
            required: true,
            attributes: [],
        }
    ]
});
```

It is mentioned here: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/