# How to search for/select by included entity but include all related entities into result set

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js, where-clause

In my application, I am using sequelize ORM. There are several entities: A `Tool` can have `Tags` and `Categories`.

Now I want to search for all `Tool`s, that have a specific `Tag`, but I want to include all relating `Tag`s of that tool (not just the specific one). If I now place a `where` statement into the include, only specified `Tag`s are included into the result set (see `[2]`). I tried to limit the `Tag`s in the outer where statement (see `[1]`), but this does not help either.

### Example

Tool `A` has Tags `t1`, `t2` and `t3`. Now I want to search all Tools that have the Tag `t3`, but the result set shall contain all three tags.

Expected result:

```
Tool A
\
 - Tag t1
 - Tag t2
 - Tag t3
```

```javascript
db.Tool.scope('published').findAll({
    where: { '$tool.tag.name$': filter.tag }, // [1] Does not work
    include: [
        {
            model: db.User,
            attributes: ['id', 'username']
        },
        {
            model: db.Tag,
            attributes: ['name'],
            through: { attributes: [] },
            // [2] Would limit the result specified tag
            // where: {
            //     name: {
            //         [Op.and]: filter.tag
            //     }
            // }
        },
        {
            model: db.Category,
            attributes: ['id', 'name', 'views'],
            through: { attributes: ['relevance'] },
            where: {
                id: {
                    [Op.and]: filter.category
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    where: {
        title: {
            [Op.like]: `%${filter.term}%`,
        }
    },
    attributes: ['id', 'title', 'description', 'slug', 'docLink', 'vendor', 'vendorLink', 'views', 'status', 'createdAt'],
    order: [['title', 'ASC'], [db.Tag, 'name', 'ASC']]
})
```

I know I could perform this by performing a select via the Tag in the first place (`db.Tag.findAll()` instead of `db.Tool.findAll()`; [I've already done this elsewhere in my project](https://github.com/dialogik-tv/dialogiktv-api/blob/master/api/tag/tag.controller.js#L41)), but at the same time I also want to be able to filter by another entity (`Category`) the same way. So the `Tool.findAll()` should be the starting point.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have two where clauses in your top-level query:

```
 where: { '$tool.tag.name$': filter.tag }, // [1] Does not work
 // ...
 where: {
        title: {
            [Op.like]: `%${filter.term}%`,
        }
    },
```

I think your best approach is going to be with a `literal` subquery in the WHERE clause. Basically we want to find the ids of all of the tools that have the right tag and that contain the `filter.term`.

The subquery part for the WHERE looks something like...

```
SELECT ToolId FROM ToolTags WHERE TagId='t2';
```

Inspired by the subquery solution from this post [Sequelize - subquery in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164694/sequelize-subquery-in-where-clause)

```
// assuming your join table is named 'ToolTags' in the database--we need the real table name not the model name 
const tempSQL = sequelize.dialect.QueryGenerator.selectQuery('ToolTags',{
    attributes: ['ToolId'],
    where: {
          TagId: filter.tag
    }})
    .slice(0,-1); // to remove the ';' from the end of the SQL

db.Tool.scope('published').findAll({
    where: {
        title: {
            [Op.like]: `%${filter.term}%`,
        },
        id: {
            [Op.In]: sequelize.literal(`(${tempSQL})`)
        }
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: db.User,
            attributes: ['id', 'username']
        },
        {
            model: db.Tag,
            attributes: ['name'],
            through: { attributes: [] },
        },
       // {
       //     model: db.Category,
       //     attributes: ['id', 'name', 'views'],
       //     through: { attributes: ['relevance'] },
       //     where: {
       //         id: {
       //             [Op.and]: filter.category
       //         }
       //     }
       // }
    ],
    attributes: ['id', 'title', 'description', 'slug', 'docLink', 'vendor', 'vendorLink', 'views', 'status', 'createdAt'],
    order: [['title', 'ASC'], [db.Tag, 'name', 'ASC']]
})
```

I commented out your category join for now. I think you should try to isolate the solution for the tags before adding more onto the query.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll take a look into it and check this answer if it helped. Thanks!