# How to use subquery in sequelize to reference self table?

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to create simple query with sequelize.queryGenerator and send it via "literal" to the model query to get the results. The basic idea is to generate query like this:

```sql
select * from table t1
where id in ( 
  select id from table t2 
  where t1.productId = t2.productId 
  order by t2.validfrom desc limit 1
)
```

I can always use rawQuery for the whole thing but according to  [Sequelize - subquery in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164694/sequelize-subquery-in-where-clause) it should be able to write it with typescript support. My case is however different as I reference the subquery to the same table. I created following code:

```js
const whereSubquery: FindOptions<Pricing> = {
    attributes: ['id'],
    where: {
        ProductId: 3,
        validFrom: new Date(2021, 9, 15),
    },
    order: [['validFrom', 'desc']],
    limit: 1,
};
const subQuery: string = this.queryGenerator
    .selectQuery(Pricing.name, whereSubquery)
    .slice(0, -1); // to remove the ';' from the end of the SQL

console.log(subQuery);

const result = await this.pricingRepository.findAll({
    where: {
        id: {
            [Op.in]: SequelizeTypeScript.literal(`(${subQuery})`),
        },
    },
});
```

the console.log shows query as expected:

```sql
SELECT "id"
FROM "Pricing"
WHERE "Pricing"."ProductId" = 3
  AND "Pricing"."validFrom" = '2021-10-15 14:25:59.406 +00:00'
ORDER BY "validFrom"
DESC LIMIT 1
```

so far so good. I will replace the static value "3" with literal *t1."ProductId"* but I need the table has "t2" as alias. If it is not possible via any parameter in FindOptions I can imagine to do it all with regex. Crazy but can be done.

However the "this.pricingRepository.findAll" method produces following error:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "Pricing" does not exist
```

Well, it is true that Pricing table has no relation to itself but in subqueries it is not expected nor required.

Is there any simple way or **should I go directly to rawQuery** and write everything manually in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used two independent queryGenerators and regex to mix them together.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).